# Unable to read all the data existing in excel sheet using Java/Selenium script

Tags: selenium, testng, indexoutofboundsexception, data-driven-tests

I'm facing an issue with reading the data from an excel file (which basically contains the login credentials in the form of test data) particularly when I am using `TestNG`. The same code works fine when I run it as a normal `java` program:

> Issue Details: [Utils] [ERROR] [Error]
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Here is the code below:

Note:
a. I read the data from the excel file and then pass it onto the test method via `DataProvider` annotation.
b. Excel contains two columns namely username and password

**FetchData.java:**

```
enter code here

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class FetchData {

public Object[][] getData() throws EncryptedDocumentException,
        InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
            "E:\\test.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    int rowCount = sh.getLastRowNum();
    int colCount = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

    System.out.println("Row Count: " + rowCount);
    System.out.println("Column Count: " + colCount);

    Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][colCount];

    for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {

            data[i][j] = sh.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            System.out.print(data[i][j] + "\t");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return data;
}

}
```

**LoginTests.java(Test Class--TestNG):**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy;
import org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginTests {

static WebDriver driver;
ChromeOptions options;
FetchData fd;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {

}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] testData() throws EncryptedDocumentException,
        InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    fd = new FetchData();
    Object[][] data = fd.getData();
    return data;
}

@Test(dataProvider = "testData")
public void test(String username, String password) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
    options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

    WebElement uname = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//input[@type='email']"));
    WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("(//input[@type='password'])[1]"));
    WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//input[@value='Log In']"));

    uname.sendKeys(username);
    pwd.sendKeys(password);
    submit.click();

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created data object using rowCount and colCount.

```
Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][colCount];
```

But in the for loop condition is added like `for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++)`.So, this loop will try to execute one more time and hence `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is throwing.

Please change the condition as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
```

For Example, If the excel has only three rows and 2 columns, then data Object will be created as `Object[][] data = new Object[3][2];`. It can hold maximum of 3 rows. But the first `for` loop will be executed from index 0 to 3 (Totally 4 rows). When it tried to insert 4th row record, then `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is throwing.

**Modified Code:**

```
Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][colCount];

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {

        data[i][j] = sh.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.print(data[i][j] + "\t");

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Edit:**

`getLastRowNum()` method is 0 based.[Refer the Doc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum--). So, you need to modify your code as below in order to get all the rows data without an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

**Modified Code:**

```
//Rowcount+1 needs to be added inorder to read the last row
Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount+1][colCount];

for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {

        data[i][j] = sh.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.print(data[i][j] + "\t");

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I made changes as per your suggestion and found that the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception issue is resolved. However, the code is not fetching the data that is present in the last row. Please note that the excel data has 3 rows and 2 columns from which the code is able to fetch the first two rows whereas the last row is not being fetched. Request your suggestions on this. Thanks, Sandesh.S

Comment: How many rows you are totally having it in Excel including header ?. Can you share the `rowCount` value?

Comment: @Sandesh: Please check the edited answer. It will solve your both the problems